# How to lock the position in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, positioning

So I would like to have something like

Slide 1:

Things (position locked)

something just for slide 1

---

Slide 2:

Things (position locked)

something just for slide 2

---

Slide 3:

Things (position locked)

something just for slide 3

---

I tried using the \onslide<1>,\onslide<2> and \onslide<3>. But it works if I am adding things to an empty space. Not quite as having something locked and just change the things below.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Like this? For more information, you could have a look at the **[`beamer` manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)** (**Chapter *9 Creating Overlays***). Generally speaking, your question is not completely clear to me.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Static Text\\
\only<1>{Slide 1 Text}
\only<2>{Slide 2 Text}
\only<3>{Slide 3 Text}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]
*(Taken from version 3.63)*

### Update

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Static Text\\
\only<1>{Slide 1 Text}
\only<2>{Slide 2 Text}
\only<3>{%
\begin{theorem}
There is no largest prime number.
\end{theorem}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this work with the Theorem environment? For example if I want to add a \newtheorem{defn}{Definition}.

Comment: @leplata See update. For more, please just try it yourself and post a *clear* follow-up question that follows these recommendations: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228. You can use my code as a template for a beamer-related question. As you can see, I do not load not-needed packages etc. The code only focuses on the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost always using a normal *itemize* to structure my slides.
With a simple `<X-Y>` behind the items you can specify when (on which slides) the item should be visible.

It works nicely since it reserves the space of each item, so e.g. if you have three items and only the second one should be displayed later, LaTeX will leave the space item 2 requires and display item 3 below that.

So you could try this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Some heading}
   \begin{itemize}
      \item<1-1> Something only visible on the first slide
      \item<2-2> Something only visible on the second slide
      \item<3-3> Something only visible on the third slide
   \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you don't want the item bullets you can just customize them away.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Was this not already mentioned in the other answer?

Comment: @Mensch Thanks! Oh where? I only see the description of the ```only<X>```` option.

Comment: Well, then please make your code snippet be compilable and explain, why there is a difference between `<X>` and `<X-Y>` ....

Comment: @Mensch I'm not sure what you mean. The answer before proposes the independent `\only<X>` command, while I suggested the `\item<X-Y>`command within the itemize environment. You can also write `\item<X-X>` as `\item<X>` though. I just thought, that someone new to this might find it interesting that X-Y is also a possible option.